# Why would layer be nil, after wantsLayer=true?

Tags: macos, calayer, nsview

I made a new OS X project in Xcode 8, added a single (image) view.  I dragged it to the default ViewController source, to add an @IBOutlet (named "image").  Then in `viewDidLoad()`, I added:

```
image.wantsLayer = true
image.layer!.cornerRadius = 10
```

About half the time, it works fine, and about half the time, it dies with:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

while pointing at the second line, and in the debugger:

```
(lldb) po image.wantsLayer
true

(lldb) po image.layer
nil
```

Is setting `wantsLayer` supposed to create a `layer` immediately?  The documentation seems to suggest this, but I can't find a statement that makes this explicit.

I've seen a lot of code, [like this](https://github.com/benzguo/demosthenes/blob/cf183161a5807f18426ba04f629f49d07ffa18ae/demosthenes/Categories/NSView.swift), which makes an NSView do:

```
self.wantsLayer = true
self.layer!.backgroundColor = ...
```

so it seems like it ought to.  Why would `layer` be nil, after setting `wantsLayer`?  Am I supposed to set `layer` myself, even if I ask for `wantsLayer`?

Comment: see https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/appkit-for-uikit-developers/ which gives some warnings regarding how to sue layer backed view layer objects

Comment: Volker: nice resource!  What I'm getting from this is that all the code that does what I posted is actually wrong, and that I need to use the `wantsUpdateLayer` path if I want to set properties on the CALayer.  (That solves one of my problems, but not all of them.)  If you post that as an "answer", I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For layer backed views on OS X it is not recommended to interact with the layer object directly. The layer is owned by AppKit. That is described in a few more words here as well: https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/appkit-for-uikit-developers/

Now, if you subclass your view and return YES/true on `wantsUpdateLayer` property of your `NSView`, you can update the layer in `updateLayer`. Note this will lead to AppKit not calling `drawRect` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

For future searchers here's the Swift 3 code to safely set the corner radius for an image (or NSView), no subclassing needed. It's dangerous to access the layer directly because NSViews are not always backed by Core Animation layers. Instead you can create a layer-hosting view and write to that.

So, in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let layer = CALayer()
image.layer = layer
image.wantsLayer = true
image.masksToBounds = true
image.cornerRadius = 19
```